# Rails: Can't add CSS class from variable in link_to

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

SyntaxError occurs when:

```html
<% @list1.each do |list| %>
  <div class="well well-sm">
    <%= list.test_name %> <%= link_to 'Do It', '#', class: <%= list.test_type %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Tried also 
`class: <%= #{list}.test_type %>`
and so on... what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 <%= link_to 'Do It', '#', class: list.test_type  %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Do It', '#', class: "#{list.test_type}" %>
```

Comment: thanks! It was all about single quotes that i tried early after "class:" :)

Answer (score 1):

You have excess erb open tag `<%=`, instead:

```
<%= list.test_name %> <%= link_to 'Do It', '#', class: <%= list.test_type %>
^^^open          close^^  ^^open                                     ^^^open       close^^
```

use:

```
<%= list.test_name %> <%= link_to 'Do It', '#', class: list.test_type %>
```

I suggest you read [`An Introduction to ERB Templating`](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/)